# Typo in the "dev.isBored" SO jobs banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, typographical-error

Currently there are two variants of the "dev.isBored" banner: one is correct:

[image]

another contains a typo (last line not commented):

[image]

and both are being shown.

**Update:**

With mandatory freehand circle to indicate the mandatory freehand circle to indicate the typo

[image]

Comment: Thank you for completing the test. You will now be considered for the most exclusive jobs.

Comment: Seems like the dev who discovered this really `isBored()`.

Comment: @Abbas Now I'm confused because I don't know what image I should look at! :P

Comment: While we're at it, shouldn't it be `A career site that's **made** by developers, for developers`?

Comment: I think this is just an A/B test of which of these converts better. They're probably interested and are measuring the impact which is why there are two versions. I'd love it if someone from Stack Overflow could share the results of the test :)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne you *could* add "made", but "by X, for X" is a fairly common idiom. Sounds better without the extra word IMO.

Comment: @mbrig "by X, for X" isn't usually preceded by "that's".

Comment: Looks like the ad just passed the A/B test, based on this amount of interest. ;)

Comment: The coloring scheme also doesn't make sense. User defined functions/variables have the same color as keywords :o

Comment: The color of the last line makes no sense at all. Also, the font used isn't monospace. By developers they say? Can developers make banners as well?

Comment: What I want to know is what the hell are the other 35 lines? Hidden StackOverflow lore right here.

Comment: @aaron So it really should just be "A career site by developers, for developers", right?

Comment: @AndrewSvietlichnyy It’s monospace with ligatures, and the colour scheme could be anything.

Comment: @BartoszKP proly using notepad++ :p

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be `dev.job.sucks()`  ?

Comment: @hanshenrik That was line 35: `var job = dev.job // Because the next line is better this way`

Comment: Probably written in [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) where all characters which are not whitespaces are ignored.

Comment: @Jesse de Bruijne  Should be "made by" unless the thought is it's supposed to remind one of the phrase "by the people, for the people".

Comment: If we're going to fix the banner, then surely the commented text should also be in a different colour as well? /pedant-mode

Comment: I've just slain the demon that is our Ad Reporting tools and looked at all the creatives of this type we served yesterday. All the creatives we showed yesterday were correct. I'm gonna mark this status-completed.

Answer (score 42):

I'll ask the ads team if this is a test, and if so, if we can share the results.

The answer to "who reads comments anyway?" might be at hand.

---

Okay, this is a little spooky. I spoke with folks on our ads team and, after an exhaustive amount of time was spent figuring out if anyone was running a test, or why we had two nearly-identical creatives:

> ... definitely not a test! I’m not sure how this ad keeps coming back to haunt us. We fixed it literally years ago and somehow it keeps getting turned on again. I’ll find it and turn it off again today.

#### The possibilities:

1. There is an ***ad*** terlife, and we're getting messages from that realm.
2. We have no idea how our software actually works, and we're going to figure it out eventually.
3. Tim Post planned this for months just so he could create a scenario in which a very ill-conceived and horrible pun could plausibly fit.
4. It's somehow Adam Lear's fault.
5. All of the above.

It *should* stop circulating shortly, but we have no idea if or when it's going to be back. But really, if you think about it, we're just lucky it's not *this* ad:

[image: Oh ZOD NO!!!]

More realistically: We're trying to figure it out, and I think we'll end up having a swag contest around this, somehow.

Comment: 6. Someone wants swag.

Comment: OK, so which one is the real ad and which one is the ghost of ads past?

Comment: @MrLister I'm not sure if we're not sure, so I'll check to be sure, but surely the wrong one will be the one that goes away for sure.

Answer (score 20):

Sounds like SO is A/B testing.

The point of the banner isn't to display valid code. It's to get people to click.

Comment: You're being downvoted, but you may be right. It's the only difference between the two images, so they could be A/B testing to see if people click more or less often on the one with valid code.

Comment: So we should all click the one with the last line commented out and avoid the other for great justice.

Comment: we're thinking too deep about this... SO wants people to click on adverts to tell the people behind them that their code is a syntax nuke. no way. it may not be right but holy damn it's a good suggestion. +1

Comment: maybe theyre trying to test how many devs will just outright ignore comments :)